# Terraform depends_on needs to wait for an ecs container to start AND BE HEALTHY before it continues

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, health-check

Using terraform there is a `depends_on` capability for any resource type, including an ECS task-group.

ECS tasks can have a z-pages style "Health Check" behavior, when the task starts it must successfully return (usually) an HTTP 200 OK and it will be marked healthy.

Is there a mechanism where the depends_on behavior will wait/delay until there is at least one healthy task.   I think right now the depends_on behavior waits until the ECS task is created, but not provisioned or running.

This would be useful in situations such as:

- provisioning a container (such as grafana-oss) then using terraform to add graphs, etc.
- standing up rabbitmq in a container, then configuring permissions, channels, etc.

Comment: here is a similar discussion using the AWS ECS CLI 
https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/issues/897

Comment: I suspect the answer (if any) will be in Terraform custom condition-checks descried here:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/syntax#custom-condition-checks

Comment: Did you try setting `wait_for_steady_state = true` on the ECS service in your Terraform definition? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_service#wait_for_steady_state

Comment: I did, and  (that is *probably* the best correct answer) so  thanks! .. although there are undesired side effects to this, if/when an application deployment crashes the ECS circuit breaker feature kicks in and rolls the service back, then the terraform deployment will hang (for default ~20m) and timeout.   Quite obnoxious and onerous when building/testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `wait_for_steady_state = true` [attribute](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_service#wait_for_steady_state) on the ECS service Terraform definition, to get Terraform to wait for the service to be stable.

Comment: I want to post a warning - the number of issues stemming from corrupted/locked state files is substantial. 

`wait_for_steady_state = true` will make the aws terraform provider block until the latest revision of the service is initialized. otherwise it will timeout & exit ("crash"), any resources created during the session will be in a corrupt state and require you to manually import them.  Use this sparingly!